# Randomly select 10 subjects and retain all of their observations

Tags: random, sas, grouping, sample

I am stuck with a the following problem in SAS. I have a dataset of this format:

[image]

The dataet consists of 500ids with different number of observations per ID. I'm trying to randomly select 5id's and at the same time retain all of their observations. I built a random generator in the first place saving a vector with 10 numbers in the interval [1,500]. However it became clumpsy when I tried to use this vector in order to select the ids correspoding to the vector with the random numbers. To be more clear, I want my net result to be a dataset which includes all observations correspoding to ID 1,10,43, 22, 67, or any other sequence of 5 numbers.

Any tip will be more than appreciated!

Comment: This has been asked many time before.  Look for `Proc SURVEYSELECT` or "`k/n` random sampling"

Comment: You say `vector` - are you using SAS/IML?  Or base SAS?

Comment: @Richard I think you may misunderstand the question - this is a bit different than the normal sampling question (whether it's an IML question or not).

Comment: Can you show your *random generator* ?  Is there a reason you don't use the `RAND` function ?

Answer (score 1):

From your question, I assume you already have your 10 random numbers. If they are saved in a table/dataset, you can run a left join between them and your original dataset, by id. This will pull out all the original observations with the same id.

Let's say that your ramdonly selected numbers are saved in a table called "random_ids". Then, you can do:

```
proc sql;
create table want as
select distinct
t1.id,
t2.*
from random_ids as t1
left join have as t2 on t1.id = t2.id;
quit;
```

If your random numbers are not saved in a dataset, you may simply copy them to a where statement, like:

```
proc sql;
create table want as
select distinct
*
from have
where id in (1 10 43 22 67) /*here you put the ids you want*/
quit;
```

Best,

Answer (score 1):

`Proc SURVEYSELECT` is your friend.

```
data have;
  call streaminit(123);
  do _n_ = 1 to 500;
    id = rand('integer', 1e6);
    do seq = 1 to rand('integer', 35);
      output;
    end;
  end;
run;

proc surveyselect noprint data=have sampsize=5 out=want;
  cluster id;
run;

proc sql noprint;
  select count(distinct id) into :id_count trimmed from want;

%put NOTE: &=id_count;
```

If you don't have the procedure as part of your SAS license, you can do sample selection per `k/n` algorithm.  NOTE: Earliest archived post for k/n is [May 1996 SAS-L message](https://listserv.uga.edu/cgi-bin/wa?A2=SAS-L;e0af2353.9605b) which has code based on a 1995 SAS Observations magazine article.

```
proc sql noprint;
  select count(distinct id) into :N trimmed from have;

proc sort data=have;
  by id;

data want_kn;
  retain N &N k 5;

  if _n_ = 1 then call streaminit(123);

  keep = rand('uniform') < k / N;
  if keep then k = k - 1;

  do until (last.id);
    set have;
    by id;
    if keep then output;
  end;

  if k = 0 then stop;

  N = N - 1;

  drop k N keep;
run;

proc sql noprint;
  select count(distinct id) into :id_count trimmed from want_kn;

%put NOTE: &=id_count;
```